# Disable tracking for rails ahoy_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ahoy

I've recently upgraded to ahoy_email version 2.0.3 from 1.1.1 and i've been refactoring my code to work with the latest version but i'm having a bit of an issue with a piece of functionality i used to have. The problem is the following:

I want to be able to disable tracking for some of the mails that get sent.

With the changes made to ahoy_email in version 2.0.0, all of the class methods that set the ahoy_settings perform add a before_action which merges the options set from on of the three methods, i.e. `track_clicks`, `has_history` and `utm_params`, so since the options only get merged in a before_action i can't do something like the following:

```
class DigestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  has_history user: -> { @recipient }, extra: -> { {digest_message_id: @digest_message.id} }
  track_clicks campaign: "digest"

  def digest(digest_message, user, **options)
    @recipient = user
    @digest_message = digest_message
    self.class.has_history options
    ....
  end
end

DigestMailer.digest(DigestMessage.first, User.first, click: false, message: false).deliver_now
```

The options i've set in the digest action wouldn't actually get merged, since they are supposed to get merged **before calling the `digest` action**

What i could do tho, is the following:

```
class DigestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  has_history user: -> { @recipient }, extra: -> { {digest_message_id: @digest_message.id} }
  track_clicks campaign: "digest"

  def digest digest_message, user, **options
    @recipient = user
    @digest_message = digest_message
    self.ahoy_options = AhoyEmail.default_options.merge(options)
  end
end

DigestMailer.digest(DigestMessage.first, User.first, click: false, message: false).deliver_now
```

This works, because i'm overriding the `ahoy_options` attribute **after** the `before_action` callback gets called and **before** the `after_action` callbacks get called and it works.

So my question is: Is this the right way to go about this?

Because [this commit](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email/commit/4c1fe651cbc0e125da593bd1e3e914e05fce3022#diff-b5a1f45fd97f708d91674723c9f78d085dd276d40d95392e1c65426448f86052), from 3 years ago, clearly says:

> Keep old method of disabling tracking

But it's nowhere to be found in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who runs into the same problem, i've found the solution and it consists of two things:

Using a [parametrized mailer](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized.html) and using the `:if` option of the `track_clicks`, `has_history` and `utm_params`. The code can be rewritten as the following:

```
class DigestMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  has_history(
    user: -> { params[:recipient] },
    extra: -> { {digest_message_id: params[:digest_message].id} },
    if: -> { params[:options].try(:fetch, :message) != false }
  )

  track_clicks(
    campaign: "digest",
    if: -> { params[:options].try(:fetch, :track_clicks) != false }
  )

  def digest
    recipient = params[:recipient]
    digest_message = params[:digest_message]

    Rails.logger.info "Sending digest to #{recipient} with email #{recipient.data.email}"
    internal_send_digest_message(digest_message.title)
  end
end

DigestMailer.with(digest_message:DigestMessage.first, recipient: User.first, options: {track_clicks: false, message: false}).deliver_now
```

And it will work as expected.